# Node does not subscribed multipletopics

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have the following situation:
have a constructor

```
unionNode() {

//publish a marker of the reconstructed object
marker_pub= n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("final_marker_visual", 1);
sub_bounding=n.subscribe<yolo_cropper::bb>("/bounding_coordinates",10,&unionNode::bbCallback,this);
yolo_Img=n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>("/yolo_show",10,&unionNode::yoloCallback,this);
sub_depth = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>("/dmde/depth",10,&unionNode::depthCallback,this);
f=400;
Cx=376;
Cy=240;

    std::cout<<"Constructor Builded"<<std::endl;}
```

where the node must subscribe itself to the three topics above described.
I tried also with the Synchronizer message filter tools, but with the same problem.

When I run main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "union");
unionNode();
ros::spin();}
```

I see "constructor builded" text... but if I open rqt_grap or rosnode_info I see my node Union is not subscribed to any topics... What should it be?
The 3 topics are active , I v seen with rostopic echo...
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244979/node-does-not-subscribed-multipletopics/) by [alby941](https://answers.ros.org/users/28151/alby941/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-10-04**:
I don't see a `ros::NodeHandle` anywhere in your code, but you're obviously creating one somewhere. Note that if all of your `NodeHandle`s go out of scope, roscpp will stop and all of your subscribers will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

your code seems correct.

You could try to print something in your callbacks something like:

```
    void unionNode::bbCallback(const yolo_cropper::bb::ConstPtr& msg){
      std::cout<<"bbCallback"<<std::endl;
    }
```

You could try to run

> rosnode info /union

And see if the subscribers are declared

---

Originally posted by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) with karma: 312 on 2016-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0